# Significance of Capitalization in Python collections module?

Tags: python, naming-conventions, python-collections

Is there any significance to the capitalization practices for classes in the [`collections` module in Python](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections)? In particular, I find it puzzling that `OrderedDict` uses CamelCase while `defaultdict` is all lowercase. My assumption would be they would all use CamelCase since they are all classes.

[image]

Comment: I think it's to do with primary C implementation vs python implementation (for CPython)

Comment: As in Python implementations (`OrderedDict`, `Counter`) are CamelCase and primary C implementations are all lowercase?

Comment: Yes, but this isn't true (now), it might be that it used to be true (i.e. legacy)- i'll try and check

Comment: There are some hysterical raisins here - back from the 1.x days when builtin types and user defined types were totally different animals and builtin types names (`list', 'dict` etc) were actually factory functions, not classes. As to why some types are spelled in all_lower and some in CamelCase, I'm afraid Chris_Rands is mostly right - except for when some type has been initially implemented in pure python then re-implemented in C.

Comment: Straight from PEP8: "The naming conventions of Python's library are a bit of a mess, so we'll never get this completely consistent".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The naming is historical (for CPython). Originally, CamelCase classes (like `OrderedDict`) were pure python implemented and other classes (like `defaultdict`) were C-implemented. However, now the names are just legacy (mostly), since C-implementation has often been added (e.g. [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/96c6af9b207c188c52ac53ce87bb7f2dea3f328b) for `OrderedDict`- you can [see now](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L297) that the python implementation is only a fallback).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I like knowing there's some reasoning, even if it no longer is consistent.